# How much disk space is needed to let Xcode install the new iOS / visionPro simulators?

Tags: macos, xcode, disk-space, xcode-simulator, visionos

Got this error, though I have some more space 229 GB / 245 GB

RegCannot copy the image because the disk is almost full
Domain: com.apple.CoreSimulator.simdiskimaged.SimDiskImageError
Code: 14

[image]

Comment: tbh, 229 of 245 is critically low anyway. You need to clear it down a bit. The guesstimate "10% free space" really only applies to larger drives, on a tiny drive like that you should be looking at 50GB free, not 20.

Comment: Please have a look here https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735408?answerId=765944022#765944022. 
Looks like it is XCode bug, you can install SDKs via command line.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? Was it just a bug in Xcode and you didn’t need to free space or was more space needed on the OS and User Data drive?

Answer (score 1):

For development, I would target at least 50 GB free on your startup disk (maybe 40 if you don't mind the system purging aggressively). 25 GB used to be OK, but the targets are getting way bigger with AR / VR / Vision SDK (and some can really squeeze things and get by with less, but I find it too time consuming to have that little free space on my boot drive).

---

Some developers think that error message is a bug. In the past, download simulators by browser and then side load the items you need and deleting the ones you do not has helped.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes
- https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Simulator%20Runtime

You can thin simulators ruthlessly and focus on just one simulator to get past the errors installing it and then add back files as needed to the boot disk. Storing those dmg on an external drive will also help freeing up space where your main user profile and Xcode reside.

It looks like there’s a [more elegant way to call for a simulator download](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/735408?answerId=767584022#767584022) from the command line:

```
xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS
```

---

Calculating free space isn't so simple now with APFS and Time Machine
snapshots, copy on write file space allocation, optimized images and
offloaded cloud storage.

[image: macOS ventura storage settings in the System Settings app]

In my case, messages is off the charts as people send me a lot of videos, photos, etc... I would take that off a development system with only 256 GB storage. iOS files are an easy clean up as are the  simulators. Music and Photos + Videos can always be stored on an external drive if you need temporary space or permanent space on the boot volume.

Once you delete space on your Data volume, be sure to examine the snapshots and purge them / make a new backup as needed to free up that space before the 24 hour automatic purge happens.

[image: macOS Ventura disk utility view of the Data volume]

Comment: my system has a maximum of 11 GB space is there any why to use it or use old versions of devices?

Comment: Hi @Salman can you clarify what 11 GB is? Ram or free disk space or total disk space?

Comment: free disk space

Comment: What happens if you try the `xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS` it might be tight, but it also will tell you if there’s no room. @Salman